# Perform action when user change Picker value

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a piece of sample code that shows picker. It is a simplified version of project that I'm working on. I have a view model that can be updated externally (via bluetooth - in example it's simulated) and by user using Picker. I would like to perform an action (for example an update) when user changes the value. I used onChange event on binding that is set on Picker and it works but the problem is that it also is called when value is changed externally which I don't want. Does anyone knows how to make it work as I expect?

```
enum Type {
    case Type1, Type2
}
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var type = Type.Type1
    init() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            self.type = Type.Type2
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Row(type: $viewModel.type) {
                self.update()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func update() {
        // some update logic that should be called only when user changed value
        print("update")
    }
}

struct Row: View {
    @Binding var type: Type
    var action: () -> Void
    var body: some View {
        Picker("Type", selection: $type) {
            Text("Type1").tag(Type.Type1)
            Text("Type2").tag(Type.Type2)
        }
        .onChange(of: type, perform: { newType in
            print("changed: \(newType)")
            action()
        })
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I found a solution but I'm not sure if it's good one. I had to use custom binding like this:

```
struct Row: View {
    @Binding var type: Type
    var action: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        let binding = Binding(
            get: { self.type },
            set: { self.type = $0
                action()
            }
        )
        return Picker("Type", selection: binding) {
            Text("Type1").tag(Type.Type1)
            Text("Type2").tag(Type.Type2)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by externally? It's a change made from other view?

Comment: I have a bluetooth device that can send its state to this app and UI should reflect it. Also I want user to be able to change those values and send them back to the device to be saved. But with onChange when device sends its state update is also called and send back to device which I don't want because it can mess with device state.

Comment: Have you tried using a ´boolean´ variable? I don't know how are you managing the connection, but if you have some function of the type ´receive_information()´ you could set the boolean to false and use it to avoid data being sent back.